# Query works on MySQL but not in Postgres SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I would like to know how to write this ruby on rails query for a postgress database? It works via mysql, but on postgres it returns an error:

**RUBY ON RAILS QUERY**

```
response_array = Vote.
              by_leaderboard_date_range.
              joins(:user).
              joins(:event_poll_relationship).
              select('users.*, sum(points_earned) as total').
              group('user_id').
              order('total DESC').
              limit(20)
```

**ERROR**

```
2013-07-31T13:02:43.430333+00:00 app[web.3]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type integer
2013-07-31T13:02:43.430333+00:00 app[web.3]: LINE 1: ...ers"."id" = "votes"."user_id" LEFT JOIN events on events.esp...
2013-07-31T13:02:43.430333+00:00 app[web.3]:                                                              ^
2013-07-31T13:02:43.430333+00:00 app[web.3]: : SELECT  users.*, sum(points_earned) as total FROM "votes" INNER JOIN "event_poll_relationships" ON "event_poll_relationships"."id" = "votes"."event_poll_relationship_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "votes"."user_id" LEFT JOIN events on events.espn_event_id WHERE (events.espn_event_id = event_poll_relationships.espn_event_id AND events.start_date_time >= '2013-07-28 00:00:00' AND events.start_date_time <= '2013-12-31 00:00:00') GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 20):
```

**VOTE MODEL**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :by_espn_event_id, lambda {|espn_event_id| joins(:event_poll_relationship).joins('LEFT JOIN events on events.espn_event_id').where('event_poll_relationships.espn_event_id = ? AND events.espn_event_id = event_poll_relationships.espn_event_id', espn_event_id) }
  scope :by_leaderboard_date_range, joins(:event_poll_relationship).joins('LEFT JOIN events on events.espn_event_id').where('events.espn_event_id = event_poll_relationships.espn_event_id AND events.start_date_time >= ? AND events.start_date_time <= ?',LeaderBoardRange.find(1).start_date.to_datetime,LeaderBoardRange.find(1).end_date.to_datetime)
```

**RAW GENERATED SQL**

```
SELECT  users.*, sum(points_earned) as total FROM "votes" INNER JOIN "event_poll_relationships" ON "event_poll_relationships"."id" = "votes"."event_poll_relationship_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "votes"."user_id" LEFT JOIN events on events.espn_event_id WHERE (events.espn_event_id = event_poll_relationships.espn_event_id AND events.start_date_time >= '2013-07-28 00:00:00' AND events.start_date_time <= '2013-12-31 00:00:00') GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 20)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The issue was on JOIN ON in the scope. This works on both dbs: mysql and postgres

```
  scope :by_espn_event_id, lambda {|espn_event_id| joins(:event_poll_relationship).joins('LEFT JOIN events ON (events.espn_event_id = event_poll_relationships.espn_event_id)').where('event_poll_relationships.espn_event_id = ?', espn_event_id) }
  scope :by_leaderboard_date_range, joins(:event_poll_relationship).joins('LEFT JOIN events ON (events.espn_event_id = event_poll_relationships.espn_event_id)').where('events.start_date_time >= ? AND events.start_date_time <= ?',LeaderBoardRange.find(1).start_date.to_datetime,LeaderBoardRange.find(1).end_date.to_datetime)
```

**RUBY ON RAILS QUERY**

```
  # calculate leaderboard by date range
  response_array = Vote.
      by_leaderboard_date_range.
      joins(:user).
      joins(:event_poll_relationship).
      select('users.*, sum(points_earned) as total').
      group('users.id, user_id').
      order('total DESC').
      limit(20)
```

Comment: Thanks for following up with a solution. In future please try to include your Rails and PostgreSQL versions as well. Props for properly including the generated SQL though.